# Create table from JSON file in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm just learning how to use PostgreSQL and JSON. I came across this great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Zm41iZzbnI&list=LL&index=1&t=61s), but the syntax was made for SQL Server. I am trying to take the following JSON file and begin parsing it into a table with columns for squad, name, age, and powers.

The JSON code is

```
CREATE TABLE heroes (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    info json NOT NULL
);

insert into heroes (info)
values (('
      {
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
    '::json));
```

I can access the first level info of the JSON with no issue, eg

`SELECT info -> 'squadName' AS squad from heroes;`  or  `SELECT info -> 'active' AS active from heroes;`

However, when trying to dig deeper into the JSON, I end up with a single row, the correct squad name and NULL for member names:

```
SELECT info -> 'squadName' AS Squad,
        info ->'members' ->> 'name' AS Name
from heroes;
```

The tutorial uses  `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(..)` to handle this, but I am not sure of what to do in PostgreSQL.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using this as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a lateral cross join of `json_array_elements()`.

```
SELECT h.info->>'squadName' AS squad,
       m.m->>'name' AS name
       FROM heroes h
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(h.info->'members') m
                                                                      (m);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d3f79dbe4d19c0914c135fb481f87af3)

But as a side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Comment: What does the last `(m)` refer to?

Comment: @acircleda: That's just a table and column alias.

Comment: If I want to expand this to include the "powers" array, which is within "members", I suspect I would need a second cross join? Adding  `m.m->>'powers' AS power` before `FROM` does not expand the array. How could that be done?

Comment: Regarding my comment above, I figured it out here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9bc84c3e5bacdf5a23a6dac7904ed1d4